# Update model field in Django with button click on a template

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and I am having some troubles with my first web application.

My idea is to show a template on user first login with some information about the web. The template contains an "accept button" and a "continue to the webpage" button. This template should appear everytime the users login, until they click on the accept button.

I have created a new model with userID, a boolean field (terms_accepted) and a date field (terms_accepted_date) to control if the users have accepted the information, and the date when they have done so. What I want is to update the terms_accepted (from False to True), when the users click on the accept button.

Is there a simply way to modify the model from the template? I have created the correct flow, because If I modify manually the terms_accepted field from the admin site, when I enter to the page I don't see the template with the information. However, I don't know how to update the field automatically on button click.

Thanks

Comment: This is usually done by posting a form. Then you handle the model update in the view that the form is posted to.

Comment: can you post your  code, on how you implemented this. simply using a django form could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at this tutorial: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/.
In the example the form is more complicated, but you can see how the model is updated in polls/view.py